# java:35: error: cannot find symbol System.out.println

Tags: java, maps

`I wrote a simple program in java but I am getting the below error in my VScode while running it, But the same code is working fine in the online compiler. So please help me out on the same.

Thank you

***ERROR***

***ERROR***

```
chenchureddy@Chenchus-MBP Java % cd "/Users/chenchureddy/PROGRAMMING/Java/" && javac TwoSum.java 
&& java TwoSum
TwoSum.java:36: error: cannot find symbol
System.out.println("the indices are :"+ result[0]+" and "+result[1]);
      ^
  symbol:   variable out
  location: class System
Note: TwoSum.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error
```

Code In Java :

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.*;



 class TwoSum{

    public static int[] twoSum(int[] numbers, int target)
    {
        int[] result = new int[2];
        Map <Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap();

        for (int i=0; i<numbers.length; i++)
        {
            if(!map.containsKey(target-numbers[i]))
            {
                map.put(numbers[i],i);
            } 
            else
            {
                result[1]=i;
                result[0]=map.get(target-numbers[i]);
                return result;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("two numbers not found");
    }

public static void main(String[] args)
{

int[] numbers = new int[] {2,11,5,10,7,8};
int[] result = twoSum(numbers,9);
System.out.println("the indices are :"+ result[0]+" and "+result[1]);

} 
}
```

Comment: You didn't paste the correct code, as the code pasted works fine. You have a class in your package that you named `System`. Don't do that. Name it anything else.